# Getting a crash on memcpy while copying a CVPixelBufferRef when using 1080p

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm getting a crash when trying to copy a CVPixelBufferRef when the video I am getting the frame is in resolution 1080p. (1920x1080)
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x114af8000)

The code works perfectly when using 1280x720 video and no crashes.

It crashes on the 2nd last line when doing the memcpy.

*EDIT
As requested the datasize of the original CVImageBufferRef(image) and the new one(pixelBufferCopy)

The working 720p resolution : datasize of 'image': 1388224   datasize of 'pixelBufferCopy': 1385288

The crashing 1080p resolution : datasize of 'image': 3140704   datasize of 'pixelBufferCopy': 3114728

```
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(image, 0);

int bufferWidth = (int)CVPixelBufferGetWidth(image);
int bufferHeight = (int)CVPixelBufferGetHeight(image);
size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(image);
uint8_t *baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(image);

OSType typ = CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType(image);

CVImageBufferRef pixelBufferCopy = NULL;

NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],       kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
                            [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],    kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey, nil];

double dataSize = CVPixelBufferGetDataSize(image);


CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,  bufferWidth, bufferHeight, typ, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) options,  &pixelBufferCopy);

uint8_t *copyBaseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBufferCopy);

memcpy(copyBaseAddress, baseAddress, dataSize);
CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(image, 0);
```

Here is the data from the CVPixelBufferRef that crashes.

```
<CVPixelBuffer 0x1c4327b20 width=1920 height=1080 pixelFormat=420v iosurface=0x1c420dd30 planes=2>
<Plane 0 width=1920 height=1080 bytesPerRow=1920>
<Plane 1 width=960 height=540 bytesPerRow=1920>
<attributes=<CFBasicHash 0x1c5679280 [0x1b4a43310]>{type = immutable dict, count = 5,
entries =>
    0 : <CFString 0x1ad86d708 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "PixelFormatDescription"} = <CFBasicHash 0x1c5676600 [0x1b4a43310]>{type = immutable dict, count = 12,
entries =>
    1 : <CFString 0x1ad86dd08 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "FillExtendedPixelsCallback"} = <CFData 0x1c44b66e0 [0x1b4a43310]>{length = 24, capacity = 24, bytes = 0x00000000000000004804e686010000000000000000000000}
    5 : <CFString 0x1ad86d9c8 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "ContainsAlpha"} = <CFBoolean 0x1b4a43878 [0x1b4a43310]>{value = false}
    6 : <CFString 0x1ad86dba8 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "ContainsYCbCr"} = <CFBoolean 0x1b4a43868 [0x1b4a43310]>{value = true}
    7 : <CFString 0x1ad86d688 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "OpenGLESCompatibility"} = <CFBoolean 0x1b4a43868 [0x1b4a43310]>{value = true}
    9 : <CFString 0x1ad86d648 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "IOSurfaceOpenGLESTextureCompatibility"} = <CFBoolean 0x1b4a43868 [0x1b4a43310]>{value = true}
    10 : <CFString 0x1ad86dc08 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "ComponentRange"} = <CFString 0x1ad86dc28 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "VideoRange"}
    12 : <CFString 0x1ad86d628 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "IOSurfaceCoreAnimationCompatibility"} = <CFBoolean 0x1b4a43868 [0x1b4a43310]>{value = true}
    13 : <CFString 0x1ad86d668 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "IOSurfaceOpenGLESFBOCompatibility"} = <CFBoolean 0x1b4a43868 [0x1b4a43310]>{value = true}
    15 : <CFString 0x1ad86d968 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "PixelFormat"} = <CFNumber 0xb000000343230762 [0x1b4a43310]>{value = +875704438, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
    18 : <CFString 0x1ad86db88 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "BitsPerComponent"} = <CFNumber 0xb000000000000082 [0x1b4a43310]>{value = +8, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
    21 : <CFString 0x1ad86dbc8 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "ContainsRGB"} = <CFBoolean 0x1b4a43878 [0x1b4a43310]>{value = false}
    22 : <CFString 0x1ad86d9e8 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "Planes"} = (
        {
        BitsPerBlock = 8;
        BlackBlock = <10>;
    },
        {
        BitsPerBlock = 16;
        BlackBlock = <8080>;
        HorizontalSubsampling = 2;
        VerticalSubsampling = 2;
    }
)
}

    2 : <CFString 0x1ad86d4e8 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "ExtendedPixelsRight"} = <CFNumber 0xb000000000000002 [0x1b4a43310]>{value = +0, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
    3 : <CFString 0x1ad86d4c8 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "ExtendedPixelsTop"} = <CFNumber 0xb000000000000002 [0x1b4a43310]>{value = +0, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
    4 : <CFString 0x1ad86d4a8 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "ExtendedPixelsLeft"} = <CFNumber 0xb000000000000002 [0x1b4a43310]>{value = +0, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
    5 : <CFString 0x1ad86d508 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "ExtendedPixelsBottom"} = <CFNumber 0xb000000000000082 [0x1b4a43310]>{value = +8, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
}
 propagatedAttachments=<CFBasicHash 0x1c5679540 [0x1b4a43310]>{type = mutable dict, count = 7,
entries =>
    0 : <CFString 0x1ad86d268 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "CVImageBufferChromaLocationTopField"} = Left
    1 : <CFString 0x1ad86cfa8 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "CVImageBufferYCbCrMatrix"} = <CFString 0x1c4622960 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "ITU_R_709_2"}
    2 : <CFString 0x1c445d820 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "FrameMetadataDictionary"} = <CFBasicHash 0x1c5675700 [0x1b4a43310]>{type = mutable dict, count = 1,
entries =>
    0 : <CFString 0x10f3d8540 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "FrameBitsPerPixel"} = <CFNumber 0x1c4622c20 [0x1b4a43310]>{value = +0.01191023284313725422, type = kCFNumberFloat64Type}
}

    5 : <CFString 0x1ad86d088 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "CVImageBufferColorPrimaries"} = <CFString 0x1c4622cc0 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "ITU_R_709_2"}
    8 : <CFString 0x1ad86d108 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "CVImageBufferTransferFunction"} = <CFString 0x1c4622e60 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "ITU_R_709_2"}
    10 : <CFString 0x1ad86d288 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "CVImageBufferChromaLocationBottomField"} = Left
    12 : <CFString 0x1ad86ce28 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "CVFieldCount"} = <CFNumber 0xb000000000000012 [0x1b4a43310]>{value = +1, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
}
 nonPropagatedAttachments=<CFBasicHash 0x1c5679500 [0x1b4a43310]>{type = mutable dict, count = 0,
entries =>
}
>
```

Here is the CVPixelBufferRef that won't crash

```
<CVPixelBuffer 0x1c4135c20 width=1280 height=720 pixelFormat=420v iosurface=0x1c4412490 planes=2>
<Plane 0 width=1280 height=720 bytesPerRow=1280>
<Plane 1 width=640 height=360 bytesPerRow=1280>
<attributes=<CFBasicHash 0x1c5669600 [0x1b4a43310]>{type = immutable dict, count = 1,
entries =>
    0 : <CFString 0x1ad86d708 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "PixelFormatDescription"} = <CFBasicHash 0x1c1c77a80 [0x1b4a43310]>{type = immutable dict, count = 12,
entries =>
    1 : <CFString 0x1ad86dd08 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "FillExtendedPixelsCallback"} = <CFData 0x1c04a4aa0 [0x1b4a43310]>{length = 24, capacity = 24, bytes = 0x00000000000000004804e686010000000000000000000000}
    5 : <CFString 0x1ad86d9c8 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "ContainsAlpha"} = <CFBoolean 0x1b4a43878 [0x1b4a43310]>{value = false}
    6 : <CFString 0x1ad86dba8 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "ContainsYCbCr"} = <CFBoolean 0x1b4a43868 [0x1b4a43310]>{value = true}
    7 : <CFString 0x1ad86d688 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "OpenGLESCompatibility"} = <CFBoolean 0x1b4a43868 [0x1b4a43310]>{value = true}
    9 : <CFString 0x1ad86d648 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "IOSurfaceOpenGLESTextureCompatibility"} = <CFBoolean 0x1b4a43868 [0x1b4a43310]>{value = true}
    10 : <CFString 0x1ad86dc08 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "ComponentRange"} = <CFString 0x1ad86dc28 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "VideoRange"}
    12 : <CFString 0x1ad86d628 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "IOSurfaceCoreAnimationCompatibility"} = <CFBoolean 0x1b4a43868 [0x1b4a43310]>{value = true}
    13 : <CFString 0x1ad86d668 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "IOSurfaceOpenGLESFBOCompatibility"} = <CFBoolean 0x1b4a43868 [0x1b4a43310]>{value = true}
    15 : <CFString 0x1ad86d968 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "PixelFormat"} = <CFNumber 0xb000000343230762 [0x1b4a43310]>{value = +875704438, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
    18 : <CFString 0x1ad86db88 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "BitsPerComponent"} = <CFNumber 0xb000000000000082 [0x1b4a43310]>{value = +8, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
    21 : <CFString 0x1ad86dbc8 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "ContainsRGB"} = <CFBoolean 0x1b4a43878 [0x1b4a43310]>{value = false}
    22 : <CFString 0x1ad86d9e8 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "Planes"} = (
        {
        BitsPerBlock = 8;
        BlackBlock = <10>;
    },
        {
        BitsPerBlock = 16;
        BlackBlock = <8080>;
        HorizontalSubsampling = 2;
        VerticalSubsampling = 2;
    }
)
}

}
 propagatedAttachments=<CFBasicHash 0x1c5a6a440 [0x1b4a43310]>{type = mutable dict, count = 7,
entries =>
    0 : <CFString 0x1ad86d268 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "CVImageBufferChromaLocationTopField"} = Left
    1 : <CFString 0x1ad86cfa8 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "CVImageBufferYCbCrMatrix"} = <CFString 0x1c462c820 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "ITU_R_709_2"}
    2 : <CFString 0x15de15900 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "FrameMetadataDictionary"} = <CFBasicHash 0x1c5c73dc0 [0x1b4a43310]>{type = mutable dict, count = 1,
entries =>
    0 : <CFString 0x15de077a0 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "FrameBitsPerPixel"} = <CFNumber 0x1c462c9a0 [0x1b4a43310]>{value = +0.00331380208333333353, type = kCFNumberFloat64Type}
}

    5 : <CFString 0x1ad86d088 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "CVImageBufferColorPrimaries"} = <CFString 0x1c462bb20 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "ITU_R_709_2"}
    8 : <CFString 0x1ad86d108 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "CVImageBufferTransferFunction"} = <CFString 0x1c462b8e0 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "ITU_R_709_2"}
    10 : <CFString 0x1ad86d288 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "CVImageBufferChromaLocationBottomField"} = Left
    12 : <CFString 0x1ad86ce28 [0x1b4a43310]>{contents = "CVFieldCount"} = <CFNumber 0xb000000000000012 [0x1b4a43310]>{value = +1, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
}
 nonPropagatedAttachments=<CFBasicHash 0x1c5673240 [0x1b4a43310]>{type = mutable dict, count = 0,
entries =>
}
>
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions as to what may be going wrong here.

Thanks,
Code

Comment: Can you use the debugger to look at the `dataSize` of the source and destination pixel buffers?

Comment: Hi @Linuxios I will do that and report back. My instinct is that the problem is with CVPixelBufferCreate, specifically the options might not be right for 1080p.

Comment: 720p :::datasize of 'image': 1388224   datasize of 'pixelBufferCopy': 1385288            1080p :::datasize of 'image': 3140704   datasize of 'pixelBufferCopy': 3114728

Comment: @Code What model device is this crashing on? Your larger image size would exceed a 32 bit variable, so it is possible that is the cause of this crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
int bufferWidth = (int)CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(image, 0);
int bufferHeight = (int)CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(image, 0);
size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(image, 0);
uint8_t *baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(image, 0);
```

instead of their non-planar counterparts.  These appear to be bi-planar CVPixelBuffers.